# Email rejected by the server

Tags: authentication, spam

Emails from site such as Gmail and Yahoo are rejected from secureserver.net  server and treated as a spam.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Spam filters are local in nature; if you want to know why a specific server classifies some emails as "spam" then you must ask the server administrators for details. Only them may answer.

Rejecting all emails from Gmail is kind of extreme, so my guess is that this `secureserver.net` does not classify as spam the "emails from Gmail", but "*your* emails from Gmail".

(In the same way that Hotmail classifies *my* emails as spams, because my *name* contains a "forbidden word".)

Answer (score 0):

Others may be using your origin as a spam emitter, making you blacklisted to them.

Look for the reason in the error and search Twitter for clues as well.